# Bash Conditionally Remove Line Endings

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am attempting to remove line endings from specific lines in a log file. The goal is to remove line endings from matching lines then append these lines to the previous line that did not match the remove line ending condition.

**Example Log:**

```
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
Log Message Overflowing
Log Message Overflowing
Log Message Overflowing
Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
Log Message Overflowing
Log Message Overflowing
Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
```

**Example Output:**

```
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
```

I am not sure what is the best way to go about this and I have had some struggles removing line endings conditionally this way with sed.

Potentially looping over each line might be the best way?

This is what I came up with and it works, I just thought there would be a better less complicated/less linear way.

```
#!/bin/bash
PrevNoMatchLine=""
PrevMatchLine=""
while read -r line; do 
    if [[ $line =~ ^[^\[] ]]; then
        PrevMatchLine+="$line "
    else
        if [[ $PrevMatchLine ]]; then
            PrevNoMatchLine+=" $PrevMatchLine"
            PrevMatchLine=""
            echo $PrevNoMatchLine
        else
            PrevNoMatchLine=$line
        fi
        echo $line 
    fi
done < test.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /^\[/) {if (p) print p; p=$0} else p = p " " $0} END{print p}' file.log

[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing Log Message Overflowing
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
[username] [object] [ip address] [datetime] [pid] :>MESSAGE TYPE:Message
```